# PyQT5 and Python3 "exit(a.exec_())" NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new to python and trying to learn to write a GUI for a raspberry pi. I am currently just following an online tutorial to create a GUI in QT designer. My QT designer has a custom widget that I added from another developer to display an LED in the GUI. The widget/module is qledplugin.py and saved in a "python" folder under the qt5.plugins.designer, and I saved the qled.py under .local.lib.python3.5.site-packages.

I created a basic GUI and the file is saved as mainwindow.ui. I used pyuic to convert it to python3 and saved as mainwindow.py. I then wrote a basic main program called main.py to launch the GUI. There are no functions, it should simply load the GUI I created in a window. The problem I encounter is that when I run `python3 main.py` I get the following error

```
myself@my-own-computer:~/Programming/Projects/GenUi$ python3 main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
        import mainwindow
      File "/home/clint/Programming/Projects/GenUi/mainwindow.py", line 86, in <module>
        from qled import QLed
      File "/home/clint/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qled.py", line 398, in <module>
        exit(a.exec_())
    NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The code for qled.py where the error occurs is

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit
    import sys

    class Test(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setWindowTitle("QLed Test")

            _l=QGridLayout()
            self.setLayout(_l)

            self.leds=[]
            for row, shape in enumerate(QLed.shapes.keys()):
                for col, colour in enumerate(QLed.colours.keys()):
                    if colour==QLed.Grey: continue
                    led=QLed(self, onColour=colour, shape=shape)
                    _l.addWidget(led, row, col, Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.leds.append(led)

            self.toggleLeds()

        def toggleLeds(self):
            for led in self.leds: led.toggleValue()
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.toggleLeds)

    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Test()
    t.show()
    t.raise_()
exit(a.exec_())
```

at the top of the code for qled.py I have

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy, QStyleOption
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt, QSize, QTimer, QByteArray, QRectF, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
```

The code for main.py is

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import mainwindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        form = MainWindow()
        form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

'a' is defined right before the exit, but the program still sees it as undefined. I did have to modify some things for python3 since it was written in python2.7, but I'm new to python and maybe I missed something. All help appreciated.

Comment: Your code examples just have a few simple indentation errors, which are easily fixed. Please check your code carefully before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is very strict with indentation. In both cases you have not respected it. In the first case exit `(a.exec_())` is on the same level as `if __name __ == "__ main__":`, this should be inside. In the other case:

```
def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        form = MainWindow()
        form.show()
```

It is at the same level as the functions of the class, and that is a serious error since it is not a class method; You must move it out.

**qled.py**

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit
    import sys

    class Test(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setWindowTitle("QLed Test")

            _l=QGridLayout()
            self.setLayout(_l)

            self.leds=[]
            for row, shape in enumerate(QLed.shapes.keys()):
                for col, colour in enumerate(QLed.colours.keys()):
                    if colour==QLed.Grey: continue
                    led=QLed(self, onColour=colour, shape=shape)
                    _l.addWidget(led, row, col, Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.leds.append(led)

            self.toggleLeds()

        def toggleLeds(self):
            for led in self.leds: led.toggleValue()
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.toggleLeds)

    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Test()
    t.show()
    t.raise_()
    exit(a.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import mainwindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. As noted, I am a beginner and was following a tutorial with the code for my main.py, so I appreciate the specific noting of where I went wrong. The qled.py was copied from a project on github where a user created it as plugin for QT Designer so the mistakes were not mine, I just modified the imports to support pyqt5 and python3.